# list of key constants

Tags: c++, char, freeglut

I want to check for Key-Events like pressing up / pressing down ...

But the function, which I created to be called, gets a "unsigned char". I am able to check for keys like W/A/S/D with `key == 'w'`, but I don't know how to check for other keys.

Is there any list of available chars, like "\n"?

Comment: Check this: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? With "char-types", do you mean `char`, `char16_t` and `char32_t`, or do you mean code points? (Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to down vote, yet.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a list of character escape sequences [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Note that some keys have to be handled using `glutSpecialFunc()`/`glutSpecialUpFunc()`, for whose handler the following applies:

> The key argument may take one of the following defined constant values:
>
> - GLUT_KEY_F1, GLUT_KEY_F2, ..., GLUT_KEY_F12 - F1 through F12 keys
> - GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP, GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN - Page Up and Page Down keys
> - GLUT_KEY_HOME, GLUT_KEY_END - Home and End keys
> - GLUT_KEY_LEFT, GLUT_KEY_RIGHT, GLUT_KEY_UP, GLUT_KEY_DOWN - Arrow keys
> - GLUT_KEY_INSERT - Insert key

Answer (score 0):

The natural char type in C++ uses ASCII characters. Here is a list: http://www.asciitable.com/

You can check for something like newline like this:

```
if (key == '\n')
```

Comment: The plain `char` type can be used to hold characters (although it is an integral type).  The encoding for the characters is implementation and locale dependent, but it's been ages since I've seen ASCII.  (The most common today seems to be UTF-8, but ISO 8850-1 is still widespread, and was almost universal not so long ago.)

Comment: I am under the impression that char is always one byte on every architecture. How would you fit UTF-8 characters in one byte?

Comment: A multi-byte UTF-8 sequence is stored in multiple `char`s. C++ allows for the execution charset to be a multi-byte encoding (in contrast to the execution wide charset, in which a single wchar_t must be able to represent all codepoints in the chosen charset)

Comment: A `char` is one byte, by definition.  But there's no requirement that all characters fit in a single `char`; only characters in the basic execution set.  And what he's looking for has nothing to do with characters, really; he's trying to find out which key was pressed (or changed state).

Answer (score 0):

this is a nice list of enums for keys

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: That's for .Net, not C++ or GLUT.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for escape sequences.

[Here](http://www.austincc.edu/rickster/COSC1320/handouts/escchar.htm) is a complete list of C++ non-graphic characters and their escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, there is no system independent way of getting
the information you need.  What you're looking for, I think, is called a
scan code, and most systems will have a way of getting it“under
Unix, it will be something in the X library if you are running in a
window, and under Windows, it's likely to be in the Windowing library as
well.  What you'll get is the scan code plus some bits indicating the
state of the various keys like shift, control and alt; and the windowing
system will generate an event each time any key changes state.

If you're not running in a window (or in your own window), it may still
be possilbe to get some sort of key state if you're reading directly
from a terminal, although I'm not too familiar with the possiblities. 
(Remember that historically, the input interfaces were designed for
reading over a serial line, and this sort of information simply wasn't
available in the C++.)