# Capturing Arrow key keyboard event in windows form

Tags: winforms, events, opengl, keyboard-events

For Opengl view on windows Form in Visual C++ , Iam completely puzzled about how to represent arrow keys(UP ARROW, DOWN ARROW, RIGHT ARROW, LEFT ARROW) for capturing  these 4 keyboard events. For other alphabetic keys i just used....

```
 void PhotoRealisticRendering_KeyPress(Object^ sender, KeyPressEventArgs^ e){
 if(e->KeyChar=='D')
 {
 }
 }
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266045/list-of-key-constants

Comment: possible duplicate of [Up, Down, Left and Right arrow keys do not trigger KeyDown event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646998/up-down-left-and-right-arrow-keys-do-not-trigger-keydown-event)